# converting m.group(1) to string array

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, pattern-matching

The contents of `m.group(1)` contains a list of URLs extracted from a JSON/ URL using regular expressions (regex), and I need to transfer them into an `ArrayList`.

I can print out all of the lines at

```
System.out.println(googleCs.get(0));
```

However, the following gives me `Index 1 out of bounds for length 1  error`

```
System.out.println(googleCs.get(1));
```

I tried to do by using string and array and split on `"\n"` (new line) as follows:

```
String myStringGoogle = m.group(1);
String[] b = myStringGoogle.split("\n");
```

However I encounter the exact same issue

```
private static void matchPattern(
    String inputLine, Pattern pattern, BufferedWriter bw
) throws IOException {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

    while (m.find()) {
        ArrayList<String> googleCs = new ArrayList<String>();
        googleCs.add(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(googleCs.get(0));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the declaration and initialization of `googleCs` to before your loop - as is you throw away the `List` with every iteration of your loop. Populate the `List` (and program to the `List` interface, not the `ArrayList` concrete type). Print after the loop. Like,

```
private static void matchPattern(String inputLine, Pattern pattern, BufferedWriter bw)
            throws IOException 
{
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
    List<String> googleCs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        googleCs.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(googleCs);
}
```

Comment: Hi Elliott, It has not worked. Do you have any additional suggetions? 
Perhaps the issue has to do with the JSON format from which I extracted the data?

Comment: Please elaborate on "has not worked"; if "System.out.println(googleCs.get(0));" was giving you all of the records then this should as well.

Comment: Elliott, I have acheived the exact same result.  the results print out in the Intellij terminal alright, and if I write to a txt file, the information saves as a single string.  

the data in m.group(1)  was extracted from a JSON using regular expressions

Comment: @EranAriel Post your code that writes to a txt file; if you see the data in the terminal then this code is working.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to do by using string and array and split on "\n" (new line)
>   as follows:
>
> String myStringGoogle = m.group(1); String[] b =
>   myStringGoogle.split("\n");

Trying doing `myStringGoogle.split("\\n");`